# Only first thread is running using python threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Hi guys i don't know why the only block runs is my first function.

i am trying to pass my coin_counter last value to the 2nd function but my first function is not passing the value after it's release.

and also it doesn't print to the console

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import threading

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(27,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

lock = threading.Lock()

counter = 1
pulse = 0

def coin_counter():
    global counter

    lock.acquire()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(.1)
            GPIO.wait_for_edge(27, GPIO.RISING)
            #print("Pulse comming ! (%s)") %counter
            counter += 1
        return counter
    finally:
        lock.release()

print(coin_counter())

def get_pulse_count():
    while True:
        print('Hello World!')


try:
    coincounter = threading.Thread(target=coin_counter)
    getpulse = threading.Thread(target=get_pulse_count)
    coincounter.start()
    getpulse.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    coincounter.stop()
    getpulse.stop()
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your function `coin_counter` seems to never return but get stuck in a `while True:` loop. This would hang your program at your first call to `coin_counter()` which seems to happen in your `print(coin_counter())` before you do any type of threading.

Comment: i want to pass the value of coin_counter to get_pulse_count everytime i am inserting a coin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem in line `print(coin_counter())`. Its should be removed because we have infinite loop in main thread (`coin_counter()` call). No any code will be executed after this line. If we remove this line and add `sleep` into `get_pulse_count()` then it works. Also `return counter` does not required if you passing value through global variable `counter`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this resolve the problem. or?

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time
    import threading

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    GPIO.setup(27,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

    lock = threading.Lock()

    counter = 1
    pulse = 0

    def coin_counter():
        global counter
        global pulse
        lock.acquire()
        try:
            time.sleep(.1)
            GPIO.wait_for_edge(27, GPIO.RISING)
            print("Pulse comming ! ", counter)
            counter += 1
            pulse = counter
        finally:
            lock.release()

    def get_pulse_count():
        global pulse
        lock.acquire()
        try:
            print(pulse)
        finally:
            lock.release()

    while True:
        time.sleep(.1)
        try:
            coincounter = threading.Thread(target=coin_counter)
            coincounter.start()
            getpulse = threading.Thread(target=get_pulse_count)
            getpulse.start()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            coincounter.stop()
            getpulse.stop()
            GPIO.cleanup()
```